# Change database in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring

I download the Pet-Clinic project to play with and created a new database called myDB. myDB has exactly the same table and data as petclinic database. I changed data-access.properties to below and restarted my server. But the code is keep access the old petclinic database. Where else I should change? Thanks.

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password
```

Comment: It seems like spring does check for myDB with username & password when it was first loaded, but uses a different database (petclinic) once it passes initial checking. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

I don't read the Pet-Clinic project code, but you change the wrong database configuration file according to you description.

so try to find the right database config file and change it.

Comment: It seems like spring does check for myDB with username & password when it was first loaded, but uses a different database (petclinic) once it passes initial checking. Not sure why...